# Horizontal Scrolling Loop Macro for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am looking to see if it’s possible to have a macro that would scroll a Google sheet to the end at a certain speed, and then once at the end, jump to the beginning and begin again. We are trying to make a 3-month staff schedule that would be a on a giant tv and would scroll to show all the weeks.

I would have one column frozen and then that one would be brought along as the screen scrolled.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Welcome. Please share a brief description of your search/research efforts. Ref. [ask].